# Sending a list of commands to list of remote server through ssh by Java with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am new to Java (I am still in the learning process), so please I greatly appreciate it if your answer provides detailed steps that I can follow.

Here is what I am looking for
1)  I have a list of commands in txt file.
2)  I have a list of servers in another file. 
3)  I am looking to get the java program to prompt for my SSH userID/password, load the command file and the server file. And execute the commands across the servers in question. 
4)  Store the output in txt file on my local machine that I’ll parse later.

I was able to get the following Java program to login and run few commends. But as you can see, UID/password and one server only are stored in the program, and I am only reading System.out without writing the output to a file.

Please help!!!

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

/** Demonstrates a connection to a remote host via SSH. **/
public class JSSH
{
    private static final String user = "UID"; // TODO: Username of ssh account on remote machine
    private static final String host = "localhost"; // TODO: Hostname of the remote machine (eg: inst.eecs.berkeley.edu)
    private static final String password = "pass"; // TODO: Password associated with your ssh account
    private static final String command = "ls -l\n cd Downloads \n ls -l\n"; // Remote command you want to invoke

public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException, InterruptedException
{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    // TODO: You will probably want to use your client ssl certificate instead of a password
    // jsch.addIdentity(new File(new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")), ".ssh"), "id_rsa").getAbsolutePath());

    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

    // TODO: You will probably want to use your client ssl certificate instead of a password
    session.setPassword(password);

    // Not recommended - skips host check
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    // session.connect(); - ten second timeout
    session.connect(10*1000);

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

    // TODO: You will probably want to use your own input stream, instead of just reading a static string.
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());
    channel.setInputStream(is);

    // Set the destination for the data sent back (from the server)
    // TODO: You will probably want to send the response somewhere other than System.out
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

    // channel.connect(); - fifteen second timeout
    channel.connect(15 * 1000);

    // Wait three seconds for this demo to complete (ie: output to be streamed to us).
    Thread.sleep(3*1000);

    // Disconnect (close connection, clean up system resources)
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way, however I have not tested it but will help you to get the idea.

Here's my `JSSH` class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class JSSH {
    private static final String user = "UID"; 
    private static final String password = "pass";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException,
        InterruptedException, IOException {
    JSSH jssh = new JSSH();
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    for(String host : jssh.listOfhost()) {
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(getProperties());
        session.connect(10 * 1000);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

        for(String command : jssh.listOfCommand()) {
            channel.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes()));
            channel.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUT_FILE)));
            channel.connect(15 * 1000);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}

private static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    return properties;
}


    private List<String> listOfCommand() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder("command_file.txt").build();
    }

    private List<String> listOfhost() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder("host_file.txt").build();
    }
}  
}
```

And here's the `LineBuilder` class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LineBuilder {

    private String fileName;

    public LineBuilder(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public List<String> build() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Note - I have removed the comments just to make the code more crisp.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, but how can I get a prompt for UserID/Password instead of leaving in the script?

Comment: I ran the above program and it worked fine. I tested with `com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31.jar`

Comment: I think having more than one command in the command file is what's causing the issue.  When I only added one command **"ls"** to the txt file, I didn't get any errors but my output file logs has ................................."Last login: Tue Jun  9 14:30:11 2015 from localhost

**ls**SamsungATIV700T:~ myaccount$ **ls** ................................................. As you can see the command "ls" wasn't executed  properly. the "ls" appeared before and after the host name without any output. Any recommendation?

Comment: my-thoughts,  I marked your answer as the closest to finding my solution. But it really needed some tweaks  that VGR helped me to sort out. Thanks again for you help on this. VGR if you see this, you rock!!! Thanks again for your detailed help. For the complete solution, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805400/java-and-ssh-looking-to-execute-multiple-commands-from-a-file-across-a-list-of

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I provided whatever help I can in my free time.